# Understanding this program

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand this program so I can get a better grip on Python programming. I was fiddling with the program and was trying to figure out how to run it, but everytime I included a play_pigs() call, I was given an error saying argument was expected. And that is true since the code says it needs a '(self)' argument,

```
def play_pigs(self):
```

How is it that this program is ran then? I'm not really understanding this part, but I think I understand some of the other parts of the code.

Code: http://ideone.com/LuRLOu

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained

Comment: The relevant code should be in your post, not in a link. Your question should be able to stand on its own without links to other sites.

Answer (score 1):

`play_pigs()` is a method of the class `PlayerSet`.  You will have to get (e. g. create) an instance of this class on which you then can call `play_pigs()` like this, for instance:

```
playerSet = PlayerSet(1, "foo")  # or some other way to get such an instance
playerSet.play_pigs()  # do not pass "self" here, as this is implicit already
```

This answers your direct question.  I didn't check if this works at all since this would be out of the scope of SO.